# com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Tags: java, php, android

I am trying to upload image to local server using retrofit. Below is my php code.

```
<?php

require 'init.php';

if ($con) {

  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $image = $_POST['image'];

  $upload_path = "uploads/$title.jpg";

  $sql = "insert into imageinfo(title,path) values('$title', '$upload_path');";

  if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

    file_put_contents($upload_path, base64_decode($image));
    echo json_encode(array('response' => "Image uploaded successfully."));
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('response' => "Error! Image is not uploaded."));
  } 

  mysqli_close($con);

} 

?>
```

But I am getting an error like this : ***com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $***.

Then I added the following code in the class where retrofit is initialized.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
```

Now I am getting the following error : ***com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.illegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $***

Whats wrong there? Is there anything wrong in php code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient(true).create();
```

Try this.